# Program fail after EndPage() fucntion

Tags: c++, printing, mfc, windows-ce, gdi

I am working with C++ MFC framework.
Unfortunatelly I met some trouble with EndPage() function.
I debugged code and got that program fail after calling EndPage() function. I have no idea why

I put code snippet below:

```
void Druk::DrawECG(short * pointer, int channel_nr, int channelLength)
{

pointer += startSample;
switch (mode)
{
case 1:
    int offsets[12];
    
    for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
        
    {
        StartPage(hDC);
    //  pointer = 0;
        
        DrawGrid(WYDRUK_I_START_X, WYDRUK_I_START_Y, WYDRUK_I_LIMIT_X, WYDRUK_I_LIMIT_Y, PEN_WIDTH);
        DrawScaleVertic(150, 300);
        SelectObject(hDC, hFontVertic);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            offsets[i] = WYDRUK_I_OFFSET + i*WYDRUK_I_SPACE;
        }
        pointer += z*channel_nr*new_sign_len;
        //pointer += startSample;
        for (int i = 0; i < channel_nr; i++)
        {
            //pointer = memECG[channels[i]] + startSample;  
            int current = channels[i];
            //new_sign_len = new_sign_len - startSample;
            rysujEKG_Vertical(pointer, WYDRUK_I_START_X, WYDRUK_I_LIMIT_X, offsets[current]);
            ExtTextOut(hDC, WYDRUK_I_CH_CAPTION_X, offsets[current], NULL, NULL, captions[current], 3, NULL);
            pointer += channelLength;
            //int diff = channelLength - new_sign_len;
        }
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        EndPage(hDC);
        
    }
    break;
```

Comment: *I debugged code and got that program fail after calling EndPage() function* -- What exactly do you mean by "program fail"?  If there is an error, please post the error message, error number, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your random call to `GetLastError();` doesn't make sense.

You need to check the return value of every API call to see if it failed, THEN you should check that last error code.

Also, you do not do anything with `DWORD error`. Is its purpose just to see its value in Debugger? Then there is a better way: add `$err` to your Debugger's  Watch window to monitor its value. Or better yet, use `$err,hr` to get a string representation of that error.

Re: `program fail after calling EndPage() function` - did it fail "right after" that call? Like on the following line? Which line was it?